# Show that $A∪B$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Define subsets $A,B$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ by
>
> $$A=\{(x,y)∈\Bbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$$  $$B=\{(a(t) \cos t, a(t) \sin t ) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : 1≤t<∞\}$$ where $a(t)=\frac{1-t}{t}$
>
> Show that $X=A∪B$  is a connected set.

This problem is about the connectedness in general topology.

I don't know how to approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $B$ is connected, since it is the image of $[1,+\infty)$ by a continuous function. Therefore, $\overline B$ is connected too. But $\overline B=A\cup B$.

Comment: You means $(1,0)$

Comment: @S.J.peter Yes, Ido.

Comment: So, must i use $(1,0)$∈A , $(1,0)$∈(the closure of B)?

Comment: @S.J.peter What has the closure of $B$ to do with this?

Comment: then,,, I think that i can use the fact $A∩$(the closure of $B$) is not empty!
But i can't go the next step

Comment: @S.J.peter Since you already know that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, it is trivial that $A\cap\overline B\neq\emptyset$. But I really don't see why you would want to use this.

Comment: I understand now! thank you.. 
I can't understand why i cant see that! Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see why $(1,0) \in B$.

Comment: @Kundor My mistake, I've edited my answer. What do you think now?